# Hazelcast: make sure related objects are physically stored on same member

Tags: mapreduce, distributed-computing, hazelcast

I have 3 distributed maps which objects have one shared property - `identifier`. This `identifier` is used as a key for one map while 2 other maps are using cluster wide global ids as a key. There's also a Map-Reduce job that is combining related by this `identifier` object and is storing the result into another map. The idea is to minimize inter-cluster network traffic so job is communicating only with one member where it is being executed.

The question is: do I need to do any extra action to make sure partitions of different distributed maps are physically stored on one member?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[PartitionAware](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.8.5/javadoc/com/hazelcast/core/PartitionAware.html) will do this for you.

If you want to guarantee three objects reside in the same partition, their key classes should implement *PartitionAware* and return the same result from the `getPartitionKey()` method.

For example, to keep all members of the same family together:

```
public class Person implements PartitionAware, Serializable {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public Object getPartitionKey() {
        return this.lastName;
    }
```

You can verify the partition with `hazelcastInstance.getPartitionService().getPartition(key).getPartitionId()`

Partition 0 contains the first part of each of map X, map Y, map Z. Partition 1 contains the next part, etc.

Comment: The getPartitionKey() result will later be used for hashing algorithm, is this correct? The default number of partitions is 271, I hope implementing PartitionAware does not change this number?

Comment: Correct, the routing key hash is modulus by the partition count to determine the partition. The property `hazelcast.partition.count` can be varied regardless of whether `PartitionAware` is used. Fuad explains it well here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16497041/why-hazelcast-has-default-partition-count-of-271-and-what-are-the-parameters-to

Comment: It's the partitions (that contain entries) that are shared amongst the storage members.These need to be roughly the same size to avoid imbalance. Make sure that `getPartitionKey` doesn't return the same result for every input or everything will end in the same partition and your system will be in a mess.